# C# iTextSharp characters above 127 removed (Line drawing)

Tags: c#, fonts, itext

I have a font that supports line drawing characters above 127.
When I try to embed those characters in the .pdf they are removed.
Is there anyway i can force iTextSharp to use the font to display those characters?
So far i have this;

```
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("font.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(args[0]);
    
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
    cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
    cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 32);
    cb.SetCharacterSpacing(2);
    cb.BeginText();
    float y = starty;

    var line = "\u0094";
    
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        cb.ShowTextAligned(Element.ALIGN_LEFT, line, 0, y, 0);
        y -= 32;
    }
    
    cb.EndText();

    reader.Close();
```

Sample of the text I am trying to embed;

```
 ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿  
 ³ Some text               ³
 ÃÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÂÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ´
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `new StreamReader(string)` assumes UTF8 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamreader-ctor(system-string). If your file is some other encoding, you'll need to specify what it is.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman : I'm not sure the link is accurate.  If characters are being dropped in sounds like ASCII encoding is being used not UTF8.  UTF8 would not drop characters.  The link says default is UTF8 and then in the example uses System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/StreamReader.cs#L174 Looks like it defaults to UTF8, unless there's a byte order mark.

Comment: A Sample of the text I am trying to embed;
 ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÂÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÂÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿  
 ³ Some text               ³ Some text              ³Some text                 ³  
 ÃÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÂÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÅÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÅÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÂÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ´

The font I am referring to is MSLINEDRAW.ttf

Comment: There are many 8-bit file encodings, dot net used to assume a code page based on your OS install. eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-6.0 But now dotnet core defaults to UTF8. If you want to use an 8-bit encoding you'll need to be specific.